# mule xpath3 not picking up the value

Tags: mule

```
<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/healthcare/plans" doc:name="Splitter" /> 
<enricher source="#[flowVars.tempid]" target="#[xpath('/plans/planid').text ]" doc:name="Message Enricher"> 

above code working fine using xpath
```

but below code using xpath3 not picking up the text

```
 <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/healthcare/plans', payload, 'NODESET')]"  doc:name="Splitter" />
  <enricher source="#[flowVars.tempid]" target="#[xpath3('/plans/planid').text ]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things wrong with your config:

1. By default `xpath3` returns a String, so no need to call `.text`. More on this here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/
2. The source and target expressions the wrong way round. If you want to store the result of the XPath expression in a a variable then `target` is  where the variable should be and `source` is the source of the value in this case the xpath expression.
3. Your Xpath expression is wrong. No need for `/plans` as the XML is already split into individual plan nodes.

Try this:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('/healthcare/plans/*', payload, 'NODESET')]"
        doc:name="Splitter" />
<enricher source="#[xpath3('planid')]" target="#[flowVars.tempid]"
        doc:name="Message Enricher">
```

Comment: after enricher whole set of xml .not in splitted form